# String Concatenation and Formatting | Python

Tags: python

```
word1 = input("Random Name (ex. Ryan):")
word2 = input("Your name (ex. why do you need an example of your name?):")

print("To:", word1, "@gmail.com")
print("From:", word2, "@outlook.com")
```

Now you almost need to ignore everything except, word 1 and word2 for now.

Im just wondering why is that the output is

```
To:name @gmail.com
```

**and not** To:name@gmail.com

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 3):

Because in python `print` automatically adds spaces between the arguments of the print statement, i.e., things separated by commas. If you want to remove that, you can set the `sep` keyword to a different separator besides a space. Set it to a blank string to have no separator.

```
>>> print('A','string','with','spaces.')
A string with spaces.
>>> print('A','string','with','no','spaces.', sep = '')
Astringwithnospaces.
```

Comment: even if I would say the other answer is the way to go it's really nice to knw that you can change the seperator in the print function

Comment: The other answer offers more control over formatting, but this is useful too. Note there's also an `end` keyword that species/changes what is appended to the end of the string. By default it is a newline, `\n`, but you can set it to `''` to not print out to a new line.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
print("To:" + word1 + "@gmail.com")
```

Or

```
print("To:%s@gmail.com" % word1)
```

Or

```
print("To:{}@gmail.com".format(word1))
```

Or as suggested in the comment:

```
print("To:{0:s}@gmail.com".format(word1))
```

To print the value the way you want

Doing `print(some_val, some_val2, some_val3, ...)` will add a space between these values.

Comment: I would use ```print("To:{0:s}@gmail.com".format(word1))``` so that the ```{}``` make sense to people who haven't seen this notation. The ```0``` being the first item to format and the ```s``` meaning a string.